# Tkinter find_overlapping exceptions or filter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically, if the following were my program: -

```
import tkinter as tk
app = tk.TK()

canvas = tk.Canvas(app, width = 600, height = 600)
canvas.pack()
r = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 200, 50, 200, tag = 'MoveOnOverlap', fill = 'green')
c = canvas.create_rectangle(25, 80, 50, 80, tag ='DontTriggerOverlap', fill ='red')

if canvas.find_overlapping(0, 500, 400, 500):
     canvas.move('MoveOnOverlap', 2, 2)



app.mainloop()
```

How would I make it so that on overlapping, only the rectangle tagged with 'MoveOnOverlap' would cause the overlapping if statement to trigger and the rectangle tagged with 'DontTriggerOverlap' would not trigger the if statement? Is it possible to have a overlap filter of some sort where only objects with a specific tag are detected? Thank you for reading this

Comment: The underlying Tk library doesn't have any option like that for its `find` command.  You'd have to implement the tag filtering yourself - perhaps `set(canvas.find_withtag(...)) & set(canvas.find_overlapping(...))`.

Comment: @jasonharper So if I were to set up a system like this, what would it look like?  Sorry for asking such an obvious question, I'm new to python and am trying to learn it. I tried searching other places online for help with this but couldn't find anything.